# Combination of URL rewrite and proxying in apache failing - with 404 Not Found Path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, mod-proxy

Hello Apache experts ,

I have a third party http web application listening on a server on port 8080. The third party application needs request URL to be of the form

```
http://hostname:8080/?accnum=<account number>
```

However owing to a legacy integration problem the  requester web client makes the request in the form

```
https://hostname/oldcontext/?acc=&quot;<accountnumber>&quot
```

Here "oldcontext" is a fixed string and accountnumber  is a variable number

For achieving integratiion between requestor and the third party app -
I installed an apache server and use apache proxying and  apache mod rewrite rewriterule directives to convert the URL format and send it on port 8080

My apache web server configuration looks as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} acc=([^&]+)
    RewriteRule ^oldcontext/$ /?accnum=%1 [L,R=301]
    RequestHeader unset Origin

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html  
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I offcourse have enabled the necessary apache modules as follows and restarted apache

```
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod headers
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

With that done when I make a request to URL

```
http://<my hostname>/oldcontext/?acc=&quot;<account number>&quot;
```

expecting that to translate and redirect to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/?accnum=<account number>
```

However

I get following response

```
{"status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/oldcontext/"}
```

I checked that the proxying is working fine -

my request to

```
http://127.0.0.1/?accnum=<account number>
```

get correctly redirected to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/?accnum=<account number>
```

And I get expected response

The rewrite is failing though as described

And even worse
if I include a **catch all** config fr URL rewrite as follows
it still gives me same error

```
enter code here
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} acc=([^&]+)
    # RewriteRule ^oldcontext/$ /?accnum=%1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /?accnum=%1  [L,R=301]
    RequestHeader unset Origin

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html  
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

- List item

What am I missing ?

Thank you for your help

Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following configuration worked for me

From what I gather I was basically stuck getting a correct RewriteCond  that would match my URL and thus ensure my rewrite rule is fired.
Once I figured that I sought help separately just for getting a right rewrite condition ( see my other post
[Apache mod rewrite RewriteCond regex help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76612358/apache-mod-rewrite-rewritecond-regex-help-needed?noredirect=1#comment135082460_76612358) )

Since my rewritecond was NOT matching the redirect was sending teh request with "oldcontext" to the new location where "oldcontext" did not exist hence the 404 error

Once I got the pattern match for my request URL right in my RewriteCond that ensured my rewrite rule was fired . My rewriterule too was not matching and I made change as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/98959/covener and it changed the URL to the new path and then everything worked well

I am including full config for sake of completeness

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    # LogLevel alert rewrite:trace7
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^acc=[a-z&;]+([0-9]+)[a-z&;]+ [NC]
 
    RewriteRule ^/oldcontext/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/?accnum=%1 [L,R=301,B,NE]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^oldcontext/$ /?accnum=%1 [L,R=301]
> ```

This rule can never match in virtualhost context. The regex in the first parameter is matched against the decoded URL-path which begins with `/`.

Comment: Hello Covener I did not understand -  can you elaborate or rephrase your response,, Why the rule wont match  ?  To me it seems like if the request looks like        -  http://<my hostname>/oldcontext/?acc=&quot;<account number>&quot; - then it should match the regex "^oldcontext/$"

Comment: The first character is a slash, but your regex only matches strings beginning with 'o'. That's what the caret means. Add a leading slash

Comment: I tried adding a slash - and rather I tried a catch all config -- Looks liek the rewrite module isnt doing anything about the URL at all .. will keep you posted

Comment: Your comment was accurate - I did the suggested changes to the rule - the other missing part was that the "RewriteCond" since the condition was not matching  - the rule was not firing and I was getting just a proxy redirect without URL rewrite. Thanks anyways