# Apache mod rewrite RewriteCond regex help needed

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache mod_rewrite.

I have a request URL that looks as follows

```
http://11.22.33.44/somecontext/?acc=&quot:1234554321&quot:
```

I am writing an Apache `RewriteCond` directive in which I want to extract the number that appears between the two  `&quot:`.
So from `&quot:1234554321&quot:` I want to extract  `1234554321`
This number (sequence of numeric digits) is enclosed between `&quot:` and `&quot:` and this is the only one get parameter and the request string starts with `acc=` ends with  `:`

I tried writing  directive in all of the following ways

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^acc=\&quot:([0-9])&quot:$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^acc=\&quot\:([0-9])\&quot\:$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} acc=\&quot\:([0-9])\&quot\:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &quot:([0-9])&quot:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \&quot\:([0-9])\&quot\:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^acc=([^&quot:]+)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^acc=\&quot\:(d+)\&quot\:$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^acc=\&quot\:(\d+)\&quot\:$
```

And my `RewriteRule` follows right after this `RewriteCond` rule and I expect to use the extracted value using backreference `%1` in my `RewriteRule`.

Can you suggest the correct `RewriteCond` directive?

Comment: Out of all the `RewriteCond` directives you've posted the last one (only) would match the example query string you've posted and captures the sequence of digits in a backreference. If not then there might be a problem with the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ or the positioning of this rule in the `.htaccess` file (order matters). What exactly is this rule doing? And where in the config? (_Aside:_ There is no need to backslash-escape the literal `&` and `:` characters in the regex.) However, are you sure it's not `&quote;` (a semi-colon instead of a colon at the end)?

Answer (score 1):

Since I am new to mod_rewrite I I referred to http://forum.modrewrite.com/ and found that very helpful to demystify the mod_rewrite syntax

Somehow it was just the  following string did the job for me

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^acc=[a-z&:]+([0-9]+)[a-z&:]+ [NC]
```

This condition matches the get parameter in the URL

```
http://11.22.33.44/somecontext/?acc=&quot:1234554321&quot:
```

( i.e part following the ? )
denoted by  QUERY_STRING variable

And parses that as follows

- "^acc=" ==> match start of string followed by  acc=
- [a-z&:]+ = pattern match   occurances of alphabets (no case=NC) and the characters & and ;
- ([0-9]+) = for matching string grab  all numeric digits
- [a-z&:]+ = pattern match   occurances of alphabets (no case=NC) and the characters & and ;

The grabbed numeric digits  are available in back reference %1

Comment: As mentioned in my earlier comment, your last regex in the question (ie. `^acc=\&quot\:(\d+)\&quot\:$`) would also have matched the example query string you posted. (?) And from the example you posted, the `NC` flag is _not_ required. (?)